# Where can I find the Northwind database for Microsoft SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, northwind

I'm trying to find and create/import the Northwind database to practice my Linq-fu.

I cannot find it for the life of me, searching just turns me to this page, which in turn tells me to find it on the official page which isn't there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227484%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Where can I find the Northwind database?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Northwind doesn't come installed with SQL Server 2008. You can instead:

- [download *scripts* for creating the Northwind and pubs sample databases](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=06616212-0356-46A0-8DA2-EEBC53A68034&displaylang=en).
- [download Northwind and pubs MDF/LDF from Microsoft](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/northwind/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=1401). The article is titled "SQL Server 2000 Sample Databases".

They come in SQL Server 2000 format / compatibility mode. Microsoft seems to have stopped using these 2 in favour of the new sample database for SQL Server 2008: AdventureWorks.

You can [download AdventureWorks 2008 R2 SR1](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55926).

Microsoft has its [SQL Server Product Database samples at CodePlex](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Wait, it seems AdventureWorks is the recommended database to use for newer versions? Is this true?

Comment: @Sergio: yes, that's true. That's why they haven't revved NWind and pubs, but are now favoring AdventureWorks. They're showcasing SQL Server 2008 features (including Filestream).

Answer (score 5):

Try this for a step by step tutorial on how to find the download and install the Northwind and Pubs databases for Sql Server 2008.

[northwind database sql server 2008](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/InstallingNorthwindAndPub.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

For any edition of SQL SERVER. You can create the database yourself using Northwind database creation script.

Download Northwind.sql.zip from this site
https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/downloads/get/269239

then create a database called `Northwind` in your Sql Server then.
Unzip / decompress the file then open the sql file in Sql Server Management Studio
select all code (ctrl+a) then press execute.

Comment: Many thanks, only this link works for SQL 2008 and newer version!