# Cant solve this database error in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I am using 3 tier architecture with ProfileDAL and ProfileBLL. I think my code for create is fine but i always encounter this particular error.

My database name is CottonyDB.mdf. Below are the pics for the error and my web.config.

Error for database:
[image: Error for database]

web.config:
[image: web.config file]

Heres my code for create:

public class ProfileDAL
    {
        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CottonyDBString"].ToString();

```
    public int create_Account(string Username, string pwd1, string email, string mobile, string pwdSalt, string mblVerified, string emailVerified)
    {
        var returnValue = 0;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (Username,PasswordHash,Email,Mobile,PasswordSalt,MobileVerified,EmailVerified) Values (@Username,@PasswordHash,@email,@mobile,@pwdSalt,@mblVerified,@emailVerified)", con))
            {
                SqlParameter[] prms = new SqlParameter[7];

                prms[0] = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.NChar, 20);
                prms[0].Value = Username;

                prms[1] = new SqlParameter("@PasswordHash", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
                prms[1].Value = pwd1;

                prms[2] = new SqlParameter("@Email", SqlDbType.NChar, 20);
                prms[2].Value = email;

                prms[3] = new SqlParameter("@Mobile", SqlDbType.NChar, 10);
                prms[3].Value = mobile;

                prms[4] = new SqlParameter("@PasswordSalt", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
                prms[4].Value = pwdSalt;

                prms[5] = new SqlParameter("@MobileVerified", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
                prms[5].Value = mblVerified;

                prms[6] = new SqlParameter("@EmailVerified", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 10);
                prms[6].Value = emailVerified;

                cmd.Parameters.AddRange(prms);
                con.Open();
                returnValue = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();



            }
            return returnValue;




        }




    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of Visual Studio running?

Comment: How are you opening the connection? are you trying to attach the db in your code?  any custom db initialization scripts?

Comment: nope I dont have multiple instances of VS running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `Initial Catalog=CottonyDB;` from your connection string, it already knows which database to use because you are using `AttachDbFileName`.

Have a look at this SO question - [Cannot attach the file *.mdf as database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012839/cannot-attach-the-file-mdf-as-databasee)

Comment: Hi, i tried deleting the Initial Catalog = CottonyDB but it still shows an error. The error states that must declare scalar variable "@pwdsalt"

Comment: Yes but notice that you are getting a different error now.You can connect to the database now but you are getting an error while executing the SQL script.And the reason you're getting that error is pretty obvious - You're specifying a variable called pwdsalt in your insert statement but in the SqlParameter declaration you refer to it as PasswordSalt.

Comment: Ah i see in my VALUES statement i used the variables instead of the column names... i tried changing that and this time it goes through my DB.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Denis