# Can't solve the "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a form in which you can enter your email and then receives instructions on resetting the password. It has a textbox (txtEmail), a Submit button (`btnResetPassword`) and a `lblMessage`.

My C# code looks like this:

```
protected void btnResetPassword_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spResetPassword", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter paramEmail = new SqlParameter("@Email", txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.Add(paramEmail);

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(rdr["ReturnCode"]))
            {
                SendPasswordResetEmail(rdr["Email"].ToString(), rdr["UniqueId"].ToString());
                lblMessage.Text = "An email with instructions to reset your password is sent to your registered email";
            }
            else
            {
                lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                lblMessage.Text = "Username not found!";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then have a method `SendPasswordResetEmail(string email, string ID)` which works fine (SMTP).

The stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROC Spresetpassword @Email NVARCHAR(100) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @UserId INT 

    SELECT @UserId = id 
    FROM dbo.turiststbl 
    WHERE email = @Email 

    IF (@UserId IS NOT NULL) 
    BEGIN 
        --If username exists 
        DECLARE @GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 

        SET @GUID = Newid() 

        INSERT INTO tblresetpasswordrequests (id, userid, resetrequestdatetime)
        VALUES (@GUID, @UserId, Getdate()) 

        SELECT 
            1 AS ReturnCode, 
            @GUID AS UniqueId, 
            @Email AS Email 
    END 
    ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        --If username does not exist 
        SELECT 
            0 AS ReturnCode, 
            NULL AS UniqueId, 
            NULL AS Email 
    END
END
```

When I enter my email, I get the following error:

[See Screenshot Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HU290.png)

What can I do?
Edit: Database files are not local, they are on a remote server

Comment: Seems you have a database connection string problem. Can you mention current DB connection string?

Comment: From the web.config file: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Vizito-20170305102044.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Vizito-20170305102044;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
@TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of error messages. See where it says “Copy exception detail to the clipboard”? Click that and post the message to your question.

Comment: Try removing the `InitialCatalog` part on your connection string and it should working fine (I'll post an answer as clarification for this).

Comment: @DourHighArch Well, the error message is way too long. Here is the clipboard of the details http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/YALKQ

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Hmm, now it's displaying this additional information: Additional information: An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Users\Hp-Pc\Desktop\VizitoSiteMaster\Vizito\App_Data\aspnet-Vizito-20170305102044.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Comment: @Arti You need to use direct file path instead of `DataDirectory` on connection string if you want to use `LocalDb` instance. Give me a few minutes to compose full answer for your problems.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto Alright, thank you for trying! It's worth mentioning that I have other parts of web page that get data from my SQL server database just fine, but in this case where I used a different method (with stored procedure) - not. I'm looking forward to your answer

Answer (score 0):

The problem origins from connection string inside web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirector‌​y|\aspnet-Vizito-201‌​70305102044.mdf;
    Init‌​ial Catalog=aspnet-Vizito-20170305102044;
    Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here you're attempting to use `LocalDb` instance by mentioning `AttachDbFilename` parameter on connecting string attribute, and it shouldn't use `Initial Catalog` parameter on the same string.

Hence, by removing `Initial Catalog` part, the connection string should be like this:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
    AttachDbFilename=|DataDirector‌​y|\aspnet-Vizito-201‌​70305102044.mdf;
    Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Additionally, if the database file placed outside of `App_Data` directory inside the project, you may require full file path to refer its location as this:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
    AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Hp-Pc\Desktop\VizitoSiteMaster\Vizito\App_Data\aspn‌​et-Vizito-2017030510‌​2044.mdf;
    Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

**Update:**

According to OP explaining that the DB takes place on remote server instance, the connection string should use `Initial Catalog` like this:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=[server address];
    Init‌​ial Catalog=aspnet-Vizito-20170305102044; User Id=[user ID]; Password=[password]; 
    Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

NB: Replace `[server address]` with remote server IP address (with port if exists), `[user ID]` & `[password]` with user credentials used on the remote server.

References:

[SQL Server Connection String](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

[Cannot attach the file *.mdf as database](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20176660)

[An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file ....database1.mdf failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566036/an-attempt-to-attach-an-auto-named-database-for-file-database1-mdf-failed)

Comment: Pardon me, I should have mentioned that the database is not local. It's on a remote server, therefore app_data folder is empty. As I can see, there is no .mdf file on my project folder

Comment: If the DB is in remote server, avoid using `LocalDb` instance, use `Initial Catalog` and place the connection string depending on the server address & DB name instead. But I'll leave `LocalDb` problem explanations in case someone encounters same problem in the future.

Comment: Nice! I actually fixed the problem by typing SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = myServerAddress; Initial Catalog = myDataBase; User Id = myUsername; Password = myPassword;");
instead of just SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(CS); Thank you @TetsuyaYamamoto