# Unknown Connection String Executing

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I've clearly stated what connection string I need my MVC application to use in Web Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OnlineStoreDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; Initial Catalog=OnlineStoreDB; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|OnlineStoreDB.mdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Optimization" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="1.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
</configuration>
```

But when I'm running this app, following runtime error is occuring:

`Cannot attach the file 'D:\Visual Studio Projects\OnlineStore\OnlineStore\App_Data\DefaultConnection.mdf' as database 'DefaultConnection'.`

I've looked very hard to find `DefaultConnection` everywhere in my app, but nothing to avail.

Can anyone please help me find out what's goin on in the background.

Thanks in advance.

***Update***

I found this following code in file `IdentityModels.cs` which has this name `DefaultConnection` in it. Not sure what exactly its doing:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }

        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<OnlineStore.Models.Item> Items { get; set; }
    }
```

`Context` file code:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using OnlineStore.Models.MvcMusicStore.Models;

namespace OnlineStore.Models
{
    public class OnlineStoreDB : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public OnlineStoreDB()
            : base("OnlineStoreDB")
        {
            Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }
        public DbSet<Item> Items { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Brand> Brands { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Cart> Carts { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OrderDetail> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<OnlineStore.ViewModels.ShoppingCartViewModel> ShoppingCartViewModels { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that I'm deriving `Context` class (`OnlineStoreDB`) from `IdentityDBContext` instead of `DBContext` because I need to use `IdentityRoles` in my app.

Comment: Have checked that MDF file is available?

Comment: Or any special reason ti mention the MDF file nane in connection string?

Comment: This is guesswork: what user/login management code are you using? If it was generated as part of a project template, it might require you to specify what to use as the user database. Just look through that code.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale. I've deliberately deleted 'DefaultConnection.mdf` simply because I don't want my app to use it. I'm wondering why its even going there.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd, That's what. Where exactly to find code for this `DefaultConnection` connectionstring ... I tried hard to find it in my app, but no good.

Comment: @PrashantPimpale When I'm clearly telling it to use a connectionstring given in the web.config, where do you think it's picking up settings for 'DefaultConnection` connectionstring from?

Comment: Are there other connection strings inside parent web.config file? Find out where the connection string used by searching entire project against that name (i.e. `DefaultConnection`).

Comment: can you share your webconfig file?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto: I've updated my question.

Comment: @farrukhaziz: Done.

Comment: @Dad have a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/a/17031891/7124761

Comment: @PrashantPimpale, my question is not about attaching .mdf to my app. I've updated my question. Please go through it. Currently problem I'm facing is: `Context` I'm trying to use is only generating `dbo.__MigrationHistory` in the database and none from the `DBSets` entities are getting translated into SQL tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `DefaultConnection` in `ApplicationDbContext` constructor to your own connection key (i.e. `OnlineStoreDB`) like this:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("OnlineStoreDB", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<OnlineStore.Models.Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Note that `ApplicationDbContext` constructor expects loading database definitions from provided connection string from its `IdentityDbContext` constructor, and since no connection string (and database file) associated with connection which has key `DefaultConnection` the error was thrown.

**Additional note:**

Sounds like your current connection string should be modified to this one:

```
<add name="OnlineStoreDB" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB; 
     Initial Catalog=OnlineStoreDB;Integrated Security=True; 
     MultipleActiveResultSets=True; AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\OnlineStoreDB.mdf" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: After applying your suggested changes, a database with `OnlineStoreDB` is made on localDB but problem is that it has only 1 table in it named `dbo.__MigrationHistory` and none of the ASP.NET entities are translated into SQL database tables. I'm adding 'Context` file code to my question for your review. Thank you

Comment: Since you have EF Code First context definition, you need to enable migrations for adding existing DB schema (with `Enable-Migration` and `Add-Migration`, then `Update-Database`). You can read the steps [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn579398(v=vs.113).aspx) (note: the migration process seem to be different issue than this question asked for).

Comment: I noticed `\OnlineStoreDB.mdf` in your suggested connection string differs to `OnlineStoreDB.mdf` used in my connection string. I applied your code but sorry, it isn't making any difference.

Comment: The `[\]` backslash sign marks path to the database file (it follows OS path convention). Before you can use that existing DB with Code First (notice that `OnModelCreating` usage), it is necessary to enable migrations as mentioned before.

Comment: I applied Migrations and its all working now like a charm. Thanks alot bro for your help throughout. Appreciated.