# Cannot attach the file as database

Tags: c#, database, localdb

I've already seen all other post and seems cant help me.

```
String constr = (@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;
        AttachDbFilename= E:\Downloads Mainframe\Compressed\Main Menu\HRDAssets.mdf;
        initial catalog=HRDAssets; 
        Integrated Security=True;");
```

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/268002637905920001/506753130848059394/unknown.png

When I removed

```
AttachDbFilename= E:\Downloads Mainframe\Compressed\Main Menu\HRDAssets.mdf;
```

new problem pops

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/506763196225421312/506763211492556800/unknown.png

Comment: What's your question? Why can't I open a database when the connection string doesn't reference a database?

Comment: If you open the folder: `E:\Downloads Mainframe\Compressed\Main Menu\` is there a file there called HRDAssets.mdf?

Comment: the question why i am getting that error?

Comment: and how to fix it

Comment: Do you have the `HRDAssets.mdf` in its place?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot attach the file \*.mdf as database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17012839/cannot-attach-the-file-mdf-as-database)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from the connection string

```
AttachDbFilename= E:\Downloads Mainframe\Compressed\Main Menu\HRDAssets.mdf;
```

and **Initial Catalog property** I suggest to use:

```
Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\HRDAssets.mdf
```

Comment: new problem is on this screenshot
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/506763196225421312/506763211492556800/unknown.png

Comment: @Necrodor21Sa I have modified my answer